# How to make Object in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show `ul` on click. I can do it with simple jQuery but I would like to use the oop way. Please correct me if I'm wrong thanks!

**HTML**

```
 <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="toggleDropdown">
     <i class="icon-envelope"></i>
   </a>
   <ul style="display:none;" id="dropdown">
       <li><a href="#">No new messages are available</a></li>
   </ul>
</li>
```

**jQuery**

```
(function(){

var dropdowns = {

    dropDownContainer: $('#toggleDropdown'),

    dropDown : $('#dropdown'),

    init:function(){
        $(dropDownContainer).click(function(){
            dropDown.show(200);
        })
    }

};

dropdowns.init();


})();
```

Comment: Did you run it and its not work? Anyway, it seems not very oop to me... maybe take a look at [MDN - Object.prototype.constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor)?

Comment: it's not working at the moment

Answer (score 0):

The thought is not wrong, your implementation is poor. You see, referencing properties or methods from you class. You should use `this` to create instant references inside your constructor .

Here is a simple example to start with:

```
(function () {
    var testOOP = {
        container: $('a'),
        init: function (e) {
            this.container.click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(1)
            })
        }
    };
    testOOP.init();
})();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jeatqLLe/1/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to dropDown or dropDownContainer at that point; use $('#dropdown') and $('#dropDownContainer') in the init function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got it almost correct. Use "this" to refer your objects properties as follows.

```
(function(){

var dropdowns = {

    dropDownContainer: $('#toggleDropdown'),

    dropDown : $('#dropdown'),

    init:function(){
        $(this.dropDownContainer).click(function(){
            this.dropDown.show(200);
        })
    }

};

dropdowns.init();


})();
```